# create symlink to a batch file

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, symbolic-link

I create a symlink to my .bat file (test.bat)

```
mklink /D mycode test.bat
```

The problem : the symlink won't be recognized as program that I can run :

```
'mycode' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any solution ?

Answer (score 3):

I quote from the post
[How do I get my Windows7 symlink to execute from command line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32098282/how-do-i-get-my-windows7-symlink-to-execute-from-command-line)

The accepted answer by user wOxxOm says this :

> Add `.bat` extension to the symlink you create because on Windows .bat
> extension is necessary to tell the system it's actually an executable
> batch file. You will still be able to run the file by typing its name
> only.
>
> ```
> mklink C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat
> ```
>
> NTSF hardlinks can be used when source and target are on the same
> volume, the advantage is that such clones may be executed from Windows
> Explorer unlike symlinks:
>
> - `mklink /h C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat`
> - `fsutil hardlink create C:\utils\odbimport.bat C:\util-files\odbimport.bat`